# Qt / QRegExp regular expression for brackets and new lines or "\r"?

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm confused with capturing text using Qt QRegExp. I want a grab data from PHP code as simple:

```
    public function asr($x)
    {
            echo "index";
    }
```

Explanations:

```
    public function <can be more spaces or new lines...> asr($x) <can be more spaces or/and new lines or/and tabs...>
    {
            echo "index";
    }
```

What I want to grab from PHP file? This is one...

```
    public function asr($x)
    {
```

And how I'm now grabbed?

```
    QRegExp reg("(public|private|protected|static|final)(.*)function(.*)[\(](.*)[\)](.*)[\n](.*)‌​[\{]", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
```

Explanations:

When I try add `[\{]` or `(\{)` to grab a braces from PHP file it will not grab a data:

Results only:

```
    public function asr($x)
```

Instead:

```
    public function asr($x) {
```

Note: between `($x)` and  `{` can be newline `\n` or some spaces as `\s`.

This will be as `(\))(\n|\s)` but no luck :(

### Resolved results with example code:

```
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);

        // regex for function with new line
        QRegExp reg("((.*)public|private|protected|static|final)( *)function(.*)[(](.*)", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

        // capture to list
        QStringList list = reg.capturedTexts();

        qDebug() << list;

        while ( !in.atEnd() )
        {

            QString line_read = in.readLine();

            //qDebug() << line_read;        // read lines

            qDebug() << reg.exactMatch(line_read);  // find matches
        }
    }
    }


FINAL RESULTS:

false 
false 
false 
false 
false 
false 
false 
false 
true        // means found on this line for QRegExp policies
false 
false 
false 
false 
true 
false 
false 
false 
false 
true 
false 
false 
false 
false 
true 
false 
false 
false 
false 
false 
false 
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\\` for a backslash inside a `""`.

Edit:

You also don't have to escape `(){` inside a `[]`

```
QRegExp function("(public|private|protected|static|final)( *)function(.*)[(](.*)[)](.*)[{]", Qt::CaseInsensitive);
auto b = function.exactMatch( "public function ($d) \n {" );
b = function.exactMatch( "public function ($d){" );
```

works for me. The whitespace is consumed by `(.*)`

Comment: Yes, I know. It's my typo. Now is `(public|private|protected|static|final)(.*)function(.*)[\(](.*)[\)](.*)[\n](.*)[\{]` but now grabbing braces. Results: none

Comment: I received results only from `(public|private|protected|static|final)(.*)function(.*)[\(](.*)[\)](.*)`

Comment: Problem is not grabbing a brace with `(public|private|protected|static|final)(.*)function(.*)[\(](.*)[\)](.*)(\s|\n)(\{)`

Comment: I will give you point for explanations, but problem is in my edited line.

Comment: Editited the answer. Maybe it helps more this way.

Comment: But should not use exactMatch `($d) \n {"` because user can put without newline `\n` only spaces `\s`. I think should trim all strings spaces, new line and than back to write and replace...

Comment: Of course you should should use exact match. The flexibility should be in the regex. Just make the spaces or the linebreaks optional. See edit.

Comment: Let me rephrase that - it depends on what you are trying to do. You can of course use `indexIn` if you have a bigger text.

Comment: Finally, i'm solved this using read lines and checks with this regexp. It's works now with "\n" and without. Now, On questions i'm putting all source codes of examples for someone who need to help. Give you solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know what is problem, reading line by line instead of all lines on file and then should replace text in file. I should not reading a file using `in.readLine()`, so I'm finding `{` on this line, but not exists because braces `{` are on next line!